# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'myUser'

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using React hooks `useState`, `useContext`, and `createContext` to avoid props drilling and display a message in the DOM via two components (Component1 and Component2). Here,

`Jesse Hall` is the props that I'm passing from Component1 to Component2.

When I use just one file as below to hold my code, everything works fine. And the message displayed is:

```
Component 1
Hello Jesse Hall from component 1!
Component 2
Hello again Jesse Hall from component 2!
```

Below is the original code:

```
import { useState, createContext, useContext } from "react";

const UserContext = createContext();

function Component1(){
    const [user,setUser] = useState('Jesse Hall');
  
  return(
    <UserContext.Provider value={user}>
        <h1>Component 1</h1>
        <h1>Hello {user} from component 1! </h1>
        <Component2/>
    </UserContext.Provider>
  )
}

function Component2(){
  const myUser = useContext(UserContext);
  return(
    <div>
      <h2>Component 2</h2>
      <h2>{`Hello again ${myUser} from component 2!`}</h2>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Component1
```

But when I try to place the context by itself using two different files `useContext.js` and `App.js` as below, I get an error (obviously I'm doing something wrong).
The error reads:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'myUser'
```

And I don't know exactly what I'm doing wrong here.

`useContext.js`

```
import { useState, createContext, useContext } from "react";

const UserContext = createContext(undefined);

export const Component1 = ({children}) => {
    const [user] = useState('Jesse Hall');
  
  return(
    <UserContext.Provider value={user}>
        {children}
    </UserContext.Provider>
  )
}

export const useUser = () => useContext(UserContext)
```

And

`App.js`

```
import {Component1, useUser} from "./UserContext";

function App(){
  const myUser = useUser();
  console.log(myUser)
  return(
    <Component1>
    <h1>Component 1</h1>
    <h1>Hello {myUser} from component 1! </h1>
    <Component2/>
  </Component1>
  )
}

function Component2(){
  const myUser = useUser();
  return(
    <div>
      <h2>Component 2</h2>
      <h2>{`Hello again ${myUser} from component 2!`}</h2>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App;
```

and the output this time is the below. And you can tell that `myUser` is undefined in Component1.

```
Component 1
Hello from component 1!
Component 2
Hello again Jesse Hall from component 2!
```

How can I fix the bug?
Thanks

Comment: Read the [Caveats](https://react.dev/reference/react/useContext)